# Generate a type in Typescript that will have as many possible shapes that there are keys on another type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a typescript issue and i don't how to solve it.
Here is my problem.
I would like to generate a type that will have as many possible "shapes" that there are keys on another type.
Let's me explain with a "real" case.

For example, I have this custom type :

```js
interface MyFilters {
  min: number,
  max: number,
}
```

Of course, this custom type can have more than 2 properties that can be something other than `number`.

And from this `MyFilters` type, I would like to generate a type like this :

```js
type Filter =
  | {
      name: "min";
      value: number; // typeof MyFilters["min"]
    }
  | {
      name: "max";
      value: number; // typeof MyFilters["max"]
    };
```

But the `Filter` type has to be generate in a generic way, like `TFilter<MyFilters>` and not explicitly as above.

I tried something like this :

```js
interface MyFilters {
  min: number;
  max: number;
}

type TFilters<T, Key extends keyof T> = {
  name: Key;
  value: T[Key];
};
```

But with this solution, I have to specify the property name 2 times.

```js
const minFilter: TFilters<MyFilters, "min"> = {
  name: "min",
  value: 0,
};
```

So I would like to known if it can be simplify like this :

```js
// by removing "min" from generics
const minFilter: TFilters<MyFilters> = {
  name: "min",
  value: 0,
};
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mapped type will do this for you:

```
type TFilters<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    name: K;
    value: T[K];
  }
}[keyof T]

type Filters = TFilters<MyFilters>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8BiwA2koDOyA3gFDLIC2oAXMiAK6UBG0ANOVXAB52MvtSAX1Kkw6AA4oAKtjzQCAHmkA+ZAF4SnANoBpZKGQBrCOgD2MZNIC6dMhQog4lCHV0BuThQBucHA1crPWtPChEhbRNzSxtRcSlkOXwiTVlcZMUMJIUVUiA)

Comment: Thanks a lot !!
That exactly what I wanted.